# Rotating avatar at certain x coordinate Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with turning my avatar at a certain position on the map. The character moves back and forth, but he doesn't want to rotate at coordinates i entered. What am i doing wrong?

this is my code:

```
sing System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AvatarPingPong : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    public float speed;
    public float startXCord, endXCord;
    float endTrunx, startTurnx;

    public GameObject obj;
    Vector3 EndPoint, StartPoint;


    void Start () {
        EndPoint = transform.position;
        endXCord = EndPoint.x;
        endTrunx = EndPoint.x - 2f;

        StartPoint = transform.position;
        StartPoint.x = startXCord;
        startTurnx = StartPoint.x + 2f;
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        transform.position = new Vector3(PingPong (Time.time * speed, startXCord, endXCord ), transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

        if (transform.position.x == startTurnx ) {
            Debug.Log("start Check");
            obj.transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
        }

        if (transform.position.x == endTrunx ) {
            obj.transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
            Debug.Log("einde check");
        }

    }

    //function to change the default starting value of (0, 0, 0) to any value
    float PingPong(float t, float minLength, float maxLength) {
        return Mathf.PingPong(t, maxLength-minLength) + minLength;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Do you see the "start check" and "einde check" in the Unity Console?

Comment: no, but i see my coordinates of the world and the avatar are totally diffrent and don't come close

Comment: gotcha, working on an answer now, hold on a few minutes.

Comment: i fixed that by putting obj.transorm.position.x in the if statement, but somehow the statement is never true

Comment: You simply want to detect when it reaches `startXCord` and `endXCord` then rotate based on that?

Comment: yes that's basically what i want to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're trying to flip your avatar once he reaches a particular x-coordinate, but he may never reach that EXACT coordinate. `if (transform.position.x == startTurnx)` will only return true if the two values are EXACTLY the same, and your avatar isn't actually moving smoothly across the screen. He's actually jumping minute amounts every frame, so he may never land on exactly that point.

Instead, my recommendation would be to compare his new position against his old position to see which direction he's traveling in and flip him when he changes direction. Some code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AvatarPingPong : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    public float speed;
    public float startXCord, endXCord;
    float endTrunx, startTurnx;

    public GameObject obj;
    Vector3 EndPoint, StartPoint;

    //I'm going to assume you start it moving left. You may have to change this
    bool goingLeft = false;


    void Start () {
        EndPoint = transform.position;
        endXCord = EndPoint.x;
        endTrunx = EndPoint.x - 2f;

        StartPoint = transform.position;
        StartPoint.x = startXCord;
        startTurnx = StartPoint.x + 2f;
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        float prevX = transform.position.x;
        float newX = PingPong (Time.time * speed, startXCord, endXCord );
        transform.position = new Vector3(newX, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);


        if (newX > prevX) {
            //avatar is moving to the right, check to see if that's the direction it was going last Update
            if (goingLeft) {
                Debug.Log("Flipping Right");
                obj.transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
                goingLeft = false;
            }
        }else if (newX < prevX){
            //avatar is moving to the left, check to see it that's the direction it was going last Update
            if (!goingLeft) {
                Debug.Log("Flipping Left");
                obj.transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
                goingLeft = true;
            }
        }

    }

    //function to change the default starting value of (0, 0, 0) to any value
    float PingPong(float t, float minLength, float maxLength) {
        return Mathf.PingPong(t, maxLength-minLength) + minLength;
    }   
}
```

Comment: @ReiniervanRooij If it works for you don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) his answer.

Comment: @ReiniervanRooij No problem! Like Programmer said, Please take a moment to click the grey checkmark next to my answer to mark my answer as the accepted answer!

Comment: yeah sorry, i thought i had to push the up arrow and it didn't work, thanks for the explenation!

Comment: haha, no problem. I thought maybe there was some confusion about that. :)